# anemone Ruby with focus_crawl

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm working to do a crawl, but before I crawl an entire website, I would like to shoot off a test, of to or so pages. So I was thinking something like below would work, but I keep getting a nomethoderror....

```
Anemone.crawl(self.url) do |anemone|
      anemone.focus_crawl do |crawled_page|
        crawled_page.links.slice(0..10)
        page = pages.find_or_create_by_url(crawled_page.url)
        logger.debug(page.inspect)
        page.check_for_term(self.term, crawled_page.body)
      end
    end

NoMethodError (private method `select' called for true:TrueClass):
    app/models/site.rb:14:in `crawl'
    app/controllers/sites_controller.rb:96:in `block in crawl'
    app/controllers/sites_controller.rb:95:in `crawl'
```

Basically I want to have a way to first craw only 10 pages, but I seem to be not understanding the basics here. Can someone help me out? 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Add this monkeypatch to your crawling file.

```
module Anemone
    class Core
        def kill_threads
            @tentacles.each { |thread| 
                Thread.kill(thread)  if thread.alive?
            }
        end
    end
end
```

Here is an example of how to use it after you've added it to your crawling file.Then in the file which you are running your add this to your anemone.on_every_page method

```
@counter = 0
Anemone.crawl(http://stackoverflow.com, :obey_robots => true) do |anemone|
    anemone.on_every_page do |page|
        @counter+= 1 
        if @counter > 10
            anemone.kill_threads
        end
    end
end
```

Source: https://github.com/chriskite/anemone/issues/24

Answer (score 0):

So I found the :depth_limit param and that will be ok, but I would rather limit it to # of links.

Answer (score 0):

i found your question while i was googling for anemone.

I had the same problem. And with Anemone, what i did was:

As soon as i reach the URL limit that i want, i raise an exception. The whole anemone block is inside a begin/rescue block.

In your case specific i would take another approach. I would download the page that you want to parse, and bind it to [fakeweb](http://github.com/chrisk/fakeweb). I wrote a blog entry about it, long time ago, maybe it would be useful: http://blog.bigrails.com/scraper-guide.html